# Tripple-Head Setup: Raedon 5770

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, displayport

I currently own a `Sapphire Raedon HD 5770 1GB w/ DDR5` ([Link](http://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/PID-MX27397(ME).aspx))

I've got two LCDs set up in this configuration:

```
  +---------++------+
  |         ||      |
  |    1    ||   2  |
  +---------++------+
```

Im looking into buying a new TV/Monitor, a `Samsung T240HD` (h**p://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/PID-MX22473(ME).aspx) and I'd like to set up a tripple monitor setup like this (new monitor being #3)

```
  +---------++------++---------+
  |         ||      ||         |
  |    3    ||   2  ||    1    |
  +---------++------++---------+
```

- Monitor 1: DVI
- Monitor 2: DVI
- Monitor 3: HDMI
- PS3 -> Monitor 3: HDMI2

Is this possible with my current video card? Can I plug in 2x DVI + 1x HDMI and get a third display? Or am I going to have to buy a slew of Display Port Adapters?

I know older video cards you could only have 2 active displays, but I heard that barrier was defeated with the Display-Port series video cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output ports on your card are:

1. DVI(1)
2. DVI(2)
3. HDMI
4. DisplayPort

Unfortunately DVI(2) and HDMI share some circuitry, so you cannot use them at the same time. If you want three monitors, you have to use the DisplayPort for your 3rd monitor. This may mean buying an adapter of some sort, if none of your monitors support DisplayPort natively.

Comment: PS: As proof, on that exact linked page you posted, there is the text "* To support 3 displays, one of the monitors has to support DisplayPort"